# TLS Handshake failed with error EOF when deploying Hyperledger Fabric on multi-host

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm, ca

I am trying to develop a package that allow users to dynamically deploy Hyperledger Fabric peer and orderer on multi-host.

The source code is uploaded [here](https://github.com/dodo920306/Hyperledger-fabric-multihost-dev) to clarify the question further. You can follow the following description to reproduce the problem I face.

First of all, I setup two machines on GCP, both of them have environments setup as shown as the following picture:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Z4r.png)

Then I setup docker swarm between them, with an overlay network.

I build the containers on both machine, but with a different organization name and hostname.

Then I create a channel on the first machine, deploy a chaincode and invoke it. So far, so good. The rest is some trivial steps to add the second host/organization to the channel: the first organization signs for the updated config includes organizations two and updates the channel, and finally the second host/organization join the channel by the genesis block.

However, when I look into the docker logs, errors keep showing up constantly on the both sides:

On the second machine,

```bash
...
orderer0.130.211.248.179    | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.014 UTC 043e WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] probeEndpoint -> Failed connecting to {"CAs":[{"Expired":false,"Issuer":"self","Subject":"CN=fabric-ca-server,OU=Fabric,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US"}],"Endpoint":"orderer0.34.81.53.133:7050"}: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded channel=biscechannel1
orderer0.130.211.248.179    | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.014 UTC 043f WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> Received error of type 'failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded' from orderer0.34.81.53.133:7050 channel=biscechannel1
orderer0.130.211.248.179    | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.014 UTC 0440 WARN [orderer.common.cluster.puller] connectToSomeEndpoint -> Could not connect to any endpoint of [{"CAs":[{"Expired":false,"Issuer":"self","Subject":"CN=fabric-ca-server,OU=Fabric,O=Hyperledger,ST=North Carolina,C=US"}],"Endpoint":"orderer0.34.81.53.133:7050"}] channel=biscechannel1
orderer0.130.211.248.179    | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.014 UTC 0441 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 5.000078214s with error: context canceled remoteaddress=10.0.1.5:7050
peer0.130.211.248.179       | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.414 UTC 02c2 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer0.34.81.53.133:7050': failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded channel=biscechannel1
peer0.130.211.248.179       | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.415 UTC 02c3 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Disconnected from ordering service. Attempt to re-connect in 5m4.771s channel=biscechannel1
peer0.130.211.248.179       | 2023-08-28 06:42:37.415 UTC 02c4 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 2.998565787s with error: context canceled remoteaddress=10.0.1.5:7050
...
```

On the first machine,

```bash
...
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:14.125 UTC 0abb INFO [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] hup -> 1 is starting a new election at term 2 channel=biscechannel1 node=1
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:14.125 UTC 0abc INFO [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] becomePreCandidate -> 1 became pre-candidate at term 2 channel=biscechannel1 node=1
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:14.125 UTC 0abd INFO [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] poll -> 1 received MsgPreVoteResp from 1 at term 2 channel=biscechannel1 node=1
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:14.125 UTC 0abe INFO [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] campaign -> 1 [logterm: 2, index: 8] sent MsgPreVote request to 2 at term 2 channel=biscechannel1 node=1
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:14.125 UTC 0abf ERRO [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> Failed to send StepRequest to 2, because: EOF channel=biscechannel1 node=1
orderer0.34.81.53.133    | 2023-08-28 06:42:17.008 UTC 0ac0 ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 4.99736537s with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=10.0.1.11:54756
...
```

It seems like they can't reach each other, but when I try to ping a container on a machine from a container on the other machine, it actually works.

After searching on this site and the Hyperledger discord channel, most says that they solve their TLS handshake problems by adjust their CA. But as you can see in the logs, if this is a CA problem, in my limited experience, I assume there should be messages like `tls: bad certificate` or `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`, but instead it just says `TLS handshake failed with error EOF`. I know that doesn't mean that it must not be a CA problem, but I can't find what's going wrong with or without this assumation.

I recorded a video to demonstrate the whole thing [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vfg4dAN7Nw).

Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting to a server where the reverse DNS entry is set to the one(s) in the server certificate? If you have an IP address that is not listed in the subject (alternative) name then the certificate may be valid, but the machine may not be.

Comment: No, I wasn't. I add the machines' IP to the certificates now, but the problem still remains.
[Here is one of tls certificates of my orderers](https://gist.github.com/dodo920306/4c894560597ad1c733972aba84f89102).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to discover a solution just now. It appears that the mtu (Maximum Transmission Unit) value of default GCP VPC networks is initially set to `1460`, and it seems not adequate for communications between fabric peers and orderers across machines under Docker swarm, so after I increased the value to `8896`, the handshakes seldom fail again.

Answer (score 0):

They are running inside a same docker instance? This seems to me like hosts in different networks or without name resolution.

Docker containers can reach each one because it has a "internal dns resolver" by container names, but if is not, using only names without DNS resolution it is not possible. Maybe HLF hosts (CA server, Orderer and Peers) can connect with direct IP connection too, but it is unusual, and it depends of adjustments in yaml config files (configtx.yaml, orderer.yaml, core.yaml)

If you want to understand better, you can take a look in my project: https://github.com/hectordufau/dockerfabricwizard/

Comment: No, they aren't running inside a same docker instance, but I setup docker swarm between different machines with an overlay network. Doesn't that mean an internal dns resolver by all container names has been built up across machines?

Comment: Clearly this is a name resolution problem. Each container can resolve DNS names within its container orchestration, but needs an external DNS resolver to reach external hosts.